# Can you set up a differential equation for the flux for a magnet falling through a coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, differential-equations

If you drop a magnet through a coil, the experimental found emf graph looks as follows[image]

Then the flux must have the following shape:

[image]

This can be identified as a Cauchy-Lorentz distribution, which is quite common in physical experiments:

$$\Phi = \frac{k}{a+b t^2}$$ , t is time, k, a and b are constants.

The inductive voltage or emf  is defined as:

$$U_{ind}=- \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}=\frac{-2 k b t}{(a+b t^2)^2}$$

Based on these expressions it is possible to derive a differential equation,

$$(a+b t^2)\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}=-2 k b t \Phi$$

This is a nonlinear differential equation and I was asking myself if this phenomenological found differential equation also could be derived on a fundamental basis.
Can somebody help me with this?

The following formulas are also relevant:
$$\Phi= \int B dS$$

with

$$B = \frac{\mu N I}{l} $$
$$U_{ind}=I R$$ which relates $\Phi$ and I or $U_{ind}$. Also the velocity or acceleration of the magnet plays a role, $$ a=\frac{dv}{dt}= \frac {m g-F_{magnetic}}{m}$$.

Comment: What is B? The B you have written, assuming standard notation is one generated by a solenoid.

Comment: B is the field strength of the magnetic induction, generated in the coil or solenoid.

Comment: You need to know the field generated by the magnet. This in itself is quite difficult unless you assume the dipole approximation. Also the validity of the dipole approximation depends on the size of coil relative to the magnet, so you have to check if the experiment satisfies this. Also one needs to consider the self induction occurring in the coil which is usually ignored in such problems. Also if the magnet is near the edges of the coil then the equation for B is incorrect.

Comment: The magnet we used has a length of 10 cm and the coil has a length of 4.5 cm, N=400. Ignoring the issue with B, what is your opinion about the found nonlinear differential equation in the flux , based on the modeling (we choose for Cauchy distribution, not Gaussian) of this experiment? Has it physical meaning?